# Creating a load profile function in python

Tags: python, dictionary

Alright well I am trying to create a function that updates/ creates two dictionaries to include the data from the open file.

The sample text file would look something like this:

```
Dunphy, Claire  # Name of the person
Parent Teacher Association  # The networks person is associated with
Dunphy, Phil  # List of friends
Pritchett, Mitchell
Pritchett, Jay

Dunphy, Phil
Real Estate Association
Dunphy, Claire
Dunphy, Luke

Pritchett, Jay
Pritchett, Gloria
Delgado, Manny
Dunphy, Claire

def load_profiles(profiles_file, person_to_friends, person_to_networks):
```

- assume the profiles_file is allready open so no need to pass the argument to open the file
- person to friend is a dictionary, each key is a person (str) and each value is that person's friends (list of strs).
- person to networks is a dictionary, each key is a person (str) and each value is the networks that person belongs to (list of strs).

So i guess it would be easier dividing this problem in sub function/ helper function, one function that creates the person to friend dictionary and another that creates person to network dictionary.

So far for the person to friend function I have come up with:

```
def person_to_friend(profiles_file):

    person = {}
    friends = []

    for name in profiles_file:
        name = name.strip(). split('\n')

        if "," in name and name not in person.keys():
            person[key].append(name)

    return person
```

But this is returning a empty dictionary, not sure what I am doing wrong. Also not sure how to add the friends as the values for person.

Comment: Well, at first glance, it appears that you're trying to append a `name` to an empty dictionary entry. You would have to initialize that dictionary entry to a list first, and then append to it. `person[key] = []` and THEN `person[key].append(name)`.

Comment: As far as your profiles_file goes, can we assume that the order of entries is Person's name, person's network, list of friends for every single entry?

Comment: What do the last four names mean? Are these friends of Phil Dunphy? That part seems a bit inconsistent with the format.

Comment: it means that person doesnt belong to a network. so I was trying to split the file at every empty line and the first line would be the (key) person and following would be (values) list of friends

Comment: @Who8daPie that sounds like a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Despite the indentation issue in your original problem statement (which would have thrown a syntax error you would have quickly addressed), your `person_to_friend` function has a bug in its dictionary invocation: `person[key].append(name)` should read `person[key] = name`. It otherwise seems fine.

I believe your design can be refined by developing a stronger relational model that connects `persons` to `friends`, but the entire purpose of your homework exercise is to help teach you how that works! So, I'll instead be coy and not give the farm away on how to redesign your application, addressing only the technical notes here.

I would also inspect Python [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) for parsing your input file contents, because it'll give you a much simpler and more robust model for your underlying data as you try to work through your design.

Otherwise, I just wanted to thank you for providing a *wonderful* example of how to properly draft a `homework` question here on StackOverflow. Formatting aside, this is clear, concise, detail-oriented, and says very good things about your abilities as a programmer as you work through your current classes. Best of luck to you!

Comment: OP needs the `key` to correspond to a list of names, not one name.

Comment: @JoelCornett Whoops. Yep, that's my mistake for misunderstanding what was deposited in the errata. The biggest problem here is the desired backing list isn't being initialized properly, and the underlying data structures aren't being understood by the OP. I'm going to leave this here for now, though.

Answer (score 1):

Your "helper" function tries to iterate over the whole file. While using a separate function to add entries to the dictionary is not such a bad idea, it should probably be done inside a single loop, such as:

```
def load_profiles(profiles_file, person_to_friends, person_to_networks):
    friends = []
    networks = []
    for line in profiles_file:
        if not line.strip(): # we've just finished processing an entry, 
                             # need to get ready for the next one
            person_to_friends[name] = friends
            person_to_networks[name] = networks
            friends = []
            networks = []
        else:
            if friends == networks == []: # we haven't read anything yet,
                name = line               # so this must be the name
            elif ',' in line:
                friends.append(line)
            else:
                associations.append(line)
```

This is probably over-simplified (for example, it doesn't check that the networks are listed before friends), but it's already too much code for an answer to a homework question. I hope it's compensated with the bugs in it, since I haven't tested it :) Cheers.

Comment: @JoelCornett can't agree more, and that's what I always do when writing simple parsers like this one. Still, the function body looks somewhat like what I posted. The OP's assignment is sort of against the generator approach though, because different parts of the records go to different dictionaries.

Comment: @Who8daPie what do you mean? I thought we were trying to help you all right. Feel free to ask questions, if you have any.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from within the for loop, so basically you return after the first iteration.

Also, I don't quite get `name = name.strip().split('\n')`. Isn't `name` already a line from `profiles_file`?
And also make sure that `key` from `person[key].append(name)` exists and `person[key]` is a list.

I think you should rethink a little your algorithm.

EDIT:
Maybe something like this will work for you:

```
f = open(profiles_file)
person = {}
friends = []
groups = f.read().split('\n\n')
for g in groups:
    g = g.split('\n')
    person[g[0]] = []
    for friend in g[1:]:
        if ',' in friend:
             person[g[0]].append(friend)
```

Ofcourse, in order to do it without openning the file more then once you could just create 2 dictionaries or add another key to the existing one, like `person[key]['friends']` and `person[key]['networks']`. Then put an `else` to the last `if`.

Comment: Yes, `name.strip().split('\n')` is redundant as `strip()` removes whitespace characters including `\n`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but how would i 'stop' the loop at each empty line and continue creating keys and values at the next 'first' line

Comment: You could read all the text into a variable and split it for '\n\n'. this way you get a list with three strings, that you should further split for '\n'.